# Force-latest with Bower programmatic API

Tags: javascript, bower

I'm using the Bower programmatic API to install a list of libraries at once, and some of them have dependency version conflicts. I would like to use the 'force-latest' flag to default to the latest version, but I can't figure out how to make it work with the programmatic API.

The [bower documentation](http://bower.io/docs/api/#programmatic-api) shows this example:

```
var bower = require('bower');

bower.commands
.install(['jquery'], { save: true }, { /* custom config */ })
.on('end', function (installed) {
    console.log(installed);
});
```

I hoped I could change `{save: true}` to `{save: true, 'force-latest': true}` but it didn't seem to have any effect. I can handle prompts by adding `interactive: true` to the config and listening for prompt events, but I would like to make it more automated.

Does anyone know how to do this or know where there is more documentation on the programmatic API? Bower just directs you to the source code for more information. I've looked at it a bit, but I'm not really making sense of it. I'll look further if no one else knows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bower programmatic API has very little documentation so you are forced to look at their source code to figure out how to interact with it. After some digging, I have found that the 'force-latest' flag is converted to camel case when used. So, your command will need to be something like this:

```
var bower = require('bower');

bower.commands
  .install(['jquery'], { save: true, forceLatest: true }, { /* custom config */ })
  .on('end', function (installed) {
    console.log(installed);
  });
```

I hope that in the near future, the guys behind bower will offer a little more documentation to this powerful tool.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was going to dig through the source code myself, but I figured I would see if anyone in the community had done it already. It would be great to have this a little more documented.